# React Axios hanging when changing state on form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, antd

I'm trying to submit a implement a login page, where the login form is disabled while the request is processing. If I submit incorrect credentials, the form disables as expected, the request is sent, and once it returns a 401, the form is enabled again. But then if I try to submit again with the different credentials, the axios request hangs, and the promise is never resolved. My browser tab hangs and I have to close it.

Here's the code for the login page:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, NavigateFunction } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MailOutlined, KeyOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Form, Input, Typography } from 'antd';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import { DASHBOARD_ROUTE } from '../data/constants';
import styles from './Login.module.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export interface LoginProps {}

interface LoginCredentials {
  usernameOrEmail: string,
  password: string,
}

const { Title } = Typography;

// login page
const Login = (props: LoginProps): JSX.Element | null => {
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loginDisabled, setLoginDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const navigate: NavigateFunction = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = (credentials: LoginCredentials): void => {
    if (loginDisabled) {
      return;
    }

    setLoginDisabled(true);
    axios.post(
      '/accounts/jwt/create/',
      {
        username: credentials.usernameOrEmail,
        password: credentials.password
      },
      {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    ).then(() => navigate(DASHBOARD_ROUTE)
    ).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      setLoginDisabled(false);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar selectedKey='login'>
        <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Title>Login</Title>
          <Form
            name='basic'
            layout={'vertical'}
            initialValues={{ remember: true }}
            onFinish={handleLogin}
            disabled={loginDisabled}
          >
            <Form.Item
              label='Username/Email'
              name='usernameOrEmail'
              rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter your username/email' }]}
            >
              <Input
                name="usernameOrEmail"
                placeholder='Enter username/email'
                prefix={<MailOutlined />}
              />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
              label='Password'
              name='password'
              rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter your password' }]}
            >
              <Input.Password
                name="password"
                placeholder='Enter password'
                prefix={<KeyOutlined />}
                visibilityToggle={{ visible: passwordVisible, onVisibleChange: setPasswordVisible }}
              />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
              <Button
                type='primary'
                htmlType='submit'
              >
                Login
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

The way I expect to work is, the `loginDisabled` hook would be set to true right before `handleLogin` sends a request, which would set the `disabled` property of the form to `true`. Then, the axios request will be sent, and once the request returns, `loginDisabled` will be set to false again and so the form will be usable again.

Somehow, if I try to login twice, the UI freezes, and the axios request never completes. I can see in the backend that the request went through and was responded to, and the axios request interceptor is triggered, but the axios *response* interceptor is never triggered. I know I should probably have a timeout somewhere in general, but this shouldn't be happening anywhere, I think I messed up somewhere with the hooks.

A few things I've gathered:

- The backend is working properly, in fact it doesn't matter where axios sends a request, it's always freezing
- The entire problem disappears completely if I remove `setLoginDisabled` function calls. Of course that means the form is never disabled.

Any idea what's going on here? Any form of help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should consider passing `handleLogin` to the `onSubmit` event instead of `onFinish` and `loginDisabled` on the input and button elements.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what was going on: the `Navbar` component is actually also dependent on the authenticated state of a user, which was somehow causing an infinite loop somewhere. Removing (or rather refactoring) the `Navbar` did it for me.

Comment: this answer saved me a lot of time